# Am I missing an off-topic close option?

Tags: support, review, close-reasons

I'm [burning the close review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223497) and I noticed a strange issue.

Some questions list a "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." close vote:

[image]

But I have no such option under off-topic. These are the off-topic reasons I can see:

[image]

The "minimal understanding" option is not there. Reading through meta I understood the option has been removed some time ago (look in the related questions on the right), yet I see it.

Am I missing an option, is it an alias for one of the available options or is it a close vote lingering from before the voting mechanism rework?

Comment: It seems that you've _resumed_ reviewing after a (long) while.  The option was changed _ages_ back.

Comment: @devnull - The OP knows about that it was changed long back and that is why the question is asked. If it was removed long back, why is it still seen in the review queue?

Comment: The reasons are still there because they were voted for under that reason previously -- those votes still count even though the reasons changed later.

Comment: It is still possibly there because someone has flagged it when that close reason was still in place. It may have received `unclear` flag and `demonstrate minimal...`. Can you link to the question?

Comment: @devnull I noticed a couple of times before but never asked, and you have to expand the existing reason to see it, otherwise it's listed only as "off-topic".

Comment: @mehow an example is http://stackoverflow.com/q/20899522

Comment: @Albireo it's because this question is from January 3rd, back then we still had the `Demonstrate a minimal understanding` reason for closure. When I click the `close(2)` under the question it has one `unclear what you're asking` and one `off-topic` but then when I click off-topic it doesn't have a close reason selected because it doesn't exist in the GUI. The flag itself still exists. Therefore when reviewing something it lists possible reasons for closure ; one `unclear what you're asking` and the other `demonstrate..`